# How to write a for/in loop to print the second elements of all the Lists

Tags: python

I have the following lists:

```
[['Not stated', 128913], ['Response outside scope', 8457], ['Response unidentifiable', 17565], ['Other fuel(s)', 8184], ['No fuels used in this dwelling', 60819], ['Solar power', 603], ['Home heating oil', 24], ['Coal', 19203], ['Wood', 513561], ['Gas', 276666], ['Electricity', 1150047]]
```

How to write a for/in loop to print the second elements of all the Lists?

I have tried several codes posted in this website and couple others, but didn't work. I am a new in programming and studying this for my studies.

Comment: `for item in lists: print(item[1])`?

Comment: *"I have tried several codes posted in this website and couple others, but didn't work."* Will be good to see your attempts.

Comment: `print(*map(lambda x: x[1], l), sep='\n')`

Comment: @Corralien, [`itemgetter(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) is better choice over `lambda`.

Comment: @OlvinRoght. The line is too long `from operator import itemgetter; print(...)`. And `*`, `map` and `lambda` are great for functional programming :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mkrieger1 suggested:

```
lists = [['Not stated', 128913], ['Response outside scope', 8457], ['Response unidentifiable', 17565], ['Other fuel(s)', 8184], ['No fuels used in this dwelling', 60819], ['Solar power', 603], ['Home heating oil', 24], ['Coal', 19203], ['Wood', 513561], ['Gas', 276666], ['Electricity', 1150047]]

for item in lists:
    print(item[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like tally of survey responses, so I'll assume that is the context

```
for fuel, responses in survey:
    print(responses)
```

Using two or more variables in the for loop is known as multiple assignment